# Unable to compile mex file

Tags: matlab, kinect-sdk

I am using cpp files in matlab to get images from Kinect. It gives the following error:

> Error using mex (line 206)
>   Unable to complete successfully.
>
> Error in compile_cpp_files (line 47)
>          mex('-v',['-L' MicrosoftSDKPathLib],'-lMSRKinectNUI',['-I'
>          MicrosoftSDKPathInclude],Filename);

I don't know about this error and please let me know how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to configure your mex compiler using

```
>> mex -setup
```

Matlab will scan your PC to find installed compiler and suggest you which one to use.
I strongly recommend you use visual studio compiler (the latest you got).

Then try and re-run the `compile_cpp_files` script.